# Filter pandas DataFrame with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to filter a pandas DataFrame with a specific condition.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'name': ['A','A','C','C','E','E'],
                   'cat': [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3]
                  })
```

I'd like to filter by `cat == 1`. `df[df['cat'] == 1]`

However, if `1` doesn't exist as a `cat` for a name, then get the first `cat`. In this case, `A` and `C` will be filtered by `1`, for `E`, it would be `2`.

Expected output:

```
name cat
   A   1
   C   1
   E   2
```

Second part to this question:

I have additional columns that need to be retained in the DataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                       'name': ['A','A','C','C','E','E'],
                       'lbl': ['z','z','y','y','u','u'],
                       'cat': [1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 3],
                       'val1': [10, 20, 5, 10, 10, 0],
                       'yr': [90, 91, 90, 90, 90, 90]
                  })
```

The categorical variables will be part of the `groupby`, however, for `numerical` variables, I need to apply statistical functions / aggregations. `mean` for `val1` and `mode` for `yr`.

Expected output:

```
name lbl cat val1  yr
A     z   1   15   90
C     y   1   5    90
E     u   2   10   90
```

If there is a tie in mode, as is for rows with name `A`, select the first value.

Comment: Is `val1` for name `C` in expected output correct? Shouldn't it be `(5+10)/2 = 7.5` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely No, you want to filter by `cat == 1` first and then take the mean of remaining obs.

Comment: @kms please note that if you want df[df['cat'] == 1] then the expected output you provided is not correct. Because then you have two rows of A 1s.

Comment: @keramat  the two rows of A with `cat == 1` will be aggregated and therefore the `mean` would be (10+20)/2 = 15

Answer (score 2):

Another version:

```py
out = df.sort_values(
    "cat", kind="stable", key=lambda x: x != 1
).drop_duplicates("name")

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  name  cat
0    A    1
2    C    1
4    E    2
```

---

EDIT: With updated question:

```py
val1 = df[df["cat"] == 1].groupby("name")["val1"].transform("mean").dropna()
yr = df[df["cat"] == 1].groupby("name")["yr"].transform(pd.Series.mode).dropna()

df.loc[val1.index, "val1"] = val1
df.loc[yr.index, "yr"] = yr

out = df.sort_values(
    "cat", kind="stable", key=lambda x: x != 1
).drop_duplicates("name")

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  name lbl  cat  val1  yr
0    A   z    1    15  90
2    C   y    1     5  90
4    E   u    2    10  90
```

Comment: added a second part to the question, can you take a look pls?

Comment: @kms See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby `name` column then apply a customized function to get desired rows from each group.

```py
out = (df.groupby('name')
       .apply(lambda g: g[g['cat'].eq(1)] if g['cat'].eq(1).any() else g.head(1))
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(out)

  name  cat
0    A    1
1    C    1
2    E    2
```

Answer (score 1):

First we group based on the name column, Then we apply a lambda function that check the values of the cat column for each group if there is a 1 there or it will return the first value of the group. Use:

```
df.groupby('name')['cat'].apply(lambda x: 1 if 1 in x.values else x.values[0]).reset_index()
```

Output:

[image]

Based on the comment:

```
temp = df.groupby(['name', 'cat']).agg({'val1':lambda x: np.mean(x.values), 'yr': lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]}).reset_index()
temp[temp['cat']>0].groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.head(1)).set_index('name')
```

Output:

```
    cat val1    yr
name            
A   1   15.0    90
C   1   5.0 90
E   2   10.0    90
```

Comment: looks simple and elegant. can you please provide a brief explanation of what the code is doing?

Comment: Yes! Look at the answer again.

Comment: added a second part to this question. can you take a look?

Comment: Yes, I will try.

Comment: I posted minimal data on SO, and have a fairly large df in reality. when I run the code on my df, I get this error: `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0` on `yr': lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]`

Comment: I can not answer definitely without watching real data. But I guess that there are some groups with nan values. I checked the idea and it produce the same error.

Comment: You can use fillna(desired value) before the above code.

Comment: `temp[temp['cat']>0]` if a row only has `0` as `cat`, this would filter out the values. We want to retain every unique row with the `cat == 1` and if `1` is not a `cat`, then any of the next `cat`. does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244474/discussion-between-kms-and-keramat).