# How can I access any element in a pandas DataFrame for which a condition applies?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a DataFrame df

```
     0    1
0  ABC  DEF
1  abc  def
```

and a list ls

`['ABC', 'DEF', 'abc']`

and I want to check whether all entries of df are also in ls. If not, I want any of the elements not contained printed out. In this case, the code should print 'def'.

(Edit: So to clarify,  I want the **value** of a **cell** where the condition is true. Most common use-cases, which usually involve `df.loc`, only look at the **row or column** where a condition is true. But because it is not generally clear which of the cells of a row/column satisfy the condition, these don't lead to a nice solution of my problem.)

I thought of this:

```py
tmp = df.loc[(~df.isin(ls)).any(), :].iloc[0, :]
print(tmp.loc[~tmp.isin(ls)].iloc[0])
```

As this is the last thing my code should do I could also do this:

```py
df.applymap(lambda s: exit(s) if s not in ls else None)
```

But it is really ugly. Are there more elegant solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter pandas DataFrame with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103063/filter-pandas-dataframe-with-condition)

Comment: No, it doesn't. I want the value of a cell where the condition is true, and that question asks about an operation for the whole row the condition applies to. If I understood correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several option, if you just want the items that are not in `ls`, you can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and filter:

```
ls = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'abc']

out = df.stack().loc[lambda x: ~x.isin(ls)].tolist()
```

Output: `['def']`

Or use a `set` difference:

```
out = set(df.stack()).difference(ls)
```

Output: `{'def'}`